# No android module loaded Unity 2019

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

I have a problem with building 2d Unity game on android. (Unity version: 2019.4.33f1)

In the window **'Build Settings'** i choose platdorm *'Android'* and it says *'No Android module loaded'*.
[image: no android module loaded]

However when i press the button **'Install with Unity Hub'** I see that all adroid staffs already installed.
[image: loaded android modules]

Also in the tab **'Preferences'** I can't see anroid modules.
[image: preferences]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also experienced some difficulties with Unity locating my installed modules before.

If what Thomas Finet suggested above doesn't work and your AndroidPlayer path (Unity/2019.xx.xx/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer) is populated, try changing the install location of your Unity Editor.

I started using D:Editor/ for my Unity Editor version installs (e.g D:\Editor\2020.1.17f1) after having issues about "long folder path" and "non-english characters"

Answer (score 0):

ok...it seems a weird thing happened here. Unity hub may have put the module somewhere (he finds it) but not at the right place for your Editor.

I can't really recreate this myself but try this

- Open Unity hub
- Go to "Installs"
- Find your version and open the hamburger menu
- "Show in explorer"

The folder that will open should be where Unity hub is putting the modules (wrong place)

Now you have to find the android module (it may be located in a folder named "AndroidPlayer").

After all this, you just have to put this folder at your Editor location (Unity/2019.xx.xx/Editor/Data/PlaybackEngines/AndroidPlayer).

Hope this will help you figure out what happened :D

Answer (score 0):

- In Unity Hub, go to "Installs", on installed Editor, click on the gear icon:

[image]

- click on "Add Modules", and then click on checkbox for android:

[image]

- After module is installed. Go to "File-Build Settings":

[image]